# Load image on hover over <a>

Tags: html, css, hover

While I wasn't that concerned about it in the beginning, I noticed that my page size is about **9 MB** (+/- 200 images). I want to somehow decrease this by only loading the image when the user hovers over the specific `<a>`, so that only *that* image is loaded (which should decrease the page size drastically).

The code below is what I'm using right now

```
<style>
div.img {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

a:hover + div.img {
    display: block;
}
</style>

<div>
    <a href="/somename" target="_self" id="sid">Some Name</a>
    <div class="img">
        <img src="http://sub.domain.com/somename.jpg" alt="Some Name" style="some styles">
    </div>
</div>
```

I think it's possible with jQuery, but I don't know where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into lazy loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem by adapting an existing pen-code to adjust my needs (using jQuery). It now works again in IE/Firefox

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.trigger').mouseover(function() {
       // find our span
       var elem = $(this).siblings('span');

        // get our img url
       var src = elem.attr('data-original');

        // change span to img using the value from data-original
       elem.replaceWith('<img src="' + src + '" style="display:block;position:absolute;"/>');

      });

      $('.trigger').mouseout(function() {
       // find our span
       var elem = $(this).siblings('img');

        // get our img url
       var src = elem.attr('src');

        // change span to img using the value from data-original
       elem.replaceWith('<span data-original="'+src+'"></span>');
      });
    });
</script>

<a href="/gotoo" class="trigger" target="_self" id="sid">Hover over me to fetch an image</a>
<span data-original="https://lorempixel.com/g/150/200/"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have around 200 images in your directory, when a client requests the webpage it is going to have to download the images to have them ready if you are using a single page layout. I would look into lazy loading just as Adam stated. If you can also I would suggest to try to compress the photos if you can to lower the file size if possible. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can put the image with no src attribute and put the specific src in the href of div or the image!
then use jquery to get the href of a or data-src of image and then give it to the image the code will be something like this:

```
     <a class="image" href="the-src-of-the-image">
         <img src="(leave this blank)">
     </a>
```

and this is the jquery

```
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){
         $('.image').on('hover',function(){
           var img_src = $(this).attr('href');
           $(this).children('img').attr('src',img_src);
         });
      });
```

Comment: `href` and `src` are not the same in my example, so this isn't very usefull. Even though I tried this, while inspecting the element I noticed it returned `src(unknown)`.